# Angular vg-player source problem with url binding

Tags: angular, binding

I have a problem with source binding in a video player in angular

My variable campaign.campvideo contain video file's url

campaign.campvideo contain "/assets/media/CAMVXXXX.mp4"

In this case :

```
<video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" crossorigin >

     <source src="/assets/media/CAMVXXXX.mp4" type="video/mp4" >

</video>
```

it works !

But when I try

```
<video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" crossorigin >
          <source  src={{campaign?.campvideo}} type="video/mp4" >
      </video>
```

It's not working

it try different binding :

```
[src] = campaign?.campvideo
[src] = {{campaign?.campvideo}}
[src] = "{{campaign?.campvideo}}"
```

Edit : Where i retrieved campaign data

```
ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

this.campaignService.getOneCampaign(id).then(
  (campaign: Campaign) => {
    this.campaign = campaign;
    this.unitcostvid = this.campaign.unitcost * this.campaign.durationvid;
    this.totalcost = this.unitcostvid * this.campaign.nbuser;
    console.log(campaign.campvideo); /*is good */
    return this.campaign;
  }
)
```

Comment: Is the ```campaign``` data fetched async? Can you provide more details of what's "not working"? Is it a blank video, are there errors in console, etc?

Comment: No error in console...  it's blank.

Comment: How is the ```campaign``` data fetched? By using the ```?``` safe navigation operator it won't throw any exceptions or errors if it's undefined or null at the time the template is built.

Comment: yes without ? it send an error  when i use <source  src={{campaign.campvideo}} type="video/mp4" >  I got ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'campvideo' of undefined                  But with <source  [src]=campaign.campvideo type="video/mp4" > NO error but NO video

Comment: Okay, so therein lies your problem, the data is not available at the time your template is built. Including ```?``` just means your console won't throw an exception. Can you edit your original post and include your ts code where your are fetching the campaign data? Also if you are going to be using ```[src]``` and binding to the source property you need to include quotes like so: ```[src]="campaign.campvideo"```

Answer (score 0):

I put an *ngIf in HTML and it works now !

```
<source *ngIf="campaign?.campvideo"  [src]=campaign?.campvideo type="video/mp4" >
```

Thanks you all ^^